# Div element creates an unwanted margin

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a header for my website, and I gave it a div element with internal CSS, just to keep it extremely simple. Most of the CSS worked fine, but it created a strange margin around it, even though I never specified a margin in the CSS class. I tried setting it to 0px, but it did nothing.

[Screenshot. Notice the border around the blue background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/broDL.png)

```css
.headerstyle {
  background-color: #8AA3FF;
  border: 0px solid #353C41;
  height: 23px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div class=headerstyle>
  &nbsp; <a style="background-color:#68658F; color:white; padding: 0px 10px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;" href=testy.html>Home</a> &nbsp; <a style="background-color:#68658F; color:white; padding: 0px 10px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;"
    href=contents.html>Contents</a> &nbsp; <a style="background-color:#68658F; color:white; padding: 0px 10px; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: inline-block;" href=about.html>About/Contact</a>
</div>
```

Basically I'd just like the header to squeeze up against the sides of the browser window, rather than leave an empty margin. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the body element has a margin. Remove it with:

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

Answer (score 4):

As @j08691 said it's the default margin set by your browser for all pages.

You need to override it:

```
body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

A GitHub repository of all W3C HTML spec and vendor default CSS stylesheets can be found [**here**](https://github.com/sw4/revert.css)

### 1. **[Default Styles for Firefox](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/res/html.css)**

### 2. **[Default Styles for Internet Explorer](http://web.archive.org/web/20170122223926/http://www.iecss.com/)**

### 3. **[Default Styles for Chrome / Webkit](http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css)**

### 4. **[Default Styles for Opera](http://web.archive.org/web/20161031005401/http://www.iecss.com/opera-10.51.css)**

### 5. **[Default Styles for HTML4 (W3C spec)](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html)**

### 6. **[Default Styles for HTML5 (W3C spec)](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html)**

Sample, per the default W3C HTML4 spec:

```
html, address,
blockquote,
body, dd, div,
dl, dt, fieldset, form,
frame, frameset,
h1, h2, h3, h4,
h5, h6, noframes,
ol, p, ul, center,
dir, hr, menu, pre   { display: block; unicode-bidi: embed }
li              { display: list-item }
head            { display: none }
table           { display: table }
tr              { display: table-row }
thead           { display: table-header-group }
tbody           { display: table-row-group }
tfoot           { display: table-footer-group }
col             { display: table-column }
colgroup        { display: table-column-group }
td, th          { display: table-cell }
caption         { display: table-caption }
th              { font-weight: bolder; text-align: center }
caption         { text-align: center }
body            { margin: 8px }
h1              { font-size: 2em; margin: .67em 0 }
h2              { font-size: 1.5em; margin: .75em 0 }
h3              { font-size: 1.17em; margin: .83em 0 }
h4, p,
blockquote, ul,
fieldset, form,
ol, dl, dir,
menu            { margin: 1.12em 0 }
h5              { font-size: .83em; margin: 1.5em 0 }
h6              { font-size: .75em; margin: 1.67em 0 }
h1, h2, h3, h4,
h5, h6, b,
strong          { font-weight: bolder }
blockquote      { margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 40px }
i, cite, em,
var, address    { font-style: italic }
pre, tt, code,
kbd, samp       { font-family: monospace }
pre             { white-space: pre }
button, textarea,
input, select   { display: inline-block }
big             { font-size: 1.17em }
small, sub, sup { font-size: .83em }
sub             { vertical-align: sub }
sup             { vertical-align: super }
table           { border-spacing: 2px; }
thead, tbody,
tfoot           { vertical-align: middle }
td, th, tr      { vertical-align: inherit }
s, strike, del  { text-decoration: line-through }
hr              { border: 1px inset }
ol, ul, dir,
menu, dd        { margin-left: 40px }
ol              { list-style-type: decimal }
ol ul, ul ol,
ul ul, ol ol    { margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0 }
u, ins          { text-decoration: underline }
br:before       { content: "\A"; white-space: pre-line }
center          { text-align: center }
:link, :visited { text-decoration: underline }
:focus          { outline: thin dotted invert }

/* Begin bidirectionality settings (do not change) */
BDO[DIR="ltr"]  { direction: ltr; unicode-bidi: bidi-override }
BDO[DIR="rtl"]  { direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: bidi-override }

*[DIR="ltr"]    { direction: ltr; unicode-bidi: embed }
*[DIR="rtl"]    { direction: rtl; unicode-bidi: embed }

@media print {
  h1            { page-break-before: always }
  h1, h2, h3,
  h4, h5, h6    { page-break-after: avoid }
  ul, ol, dl    { page-break-before: avoid }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In some web browsers, some elements like `body` have a default `CSS`. For your case, your `body` element has `margin` `CSS`. you should make it zero.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```

But I proffer you use [`CSS Reset`](https://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/) CSS file. add it to the top level of your page, the rewrite it with your `CSS` codes.

Actually, this method is for Cross-Browser result.